# nltk_data installation gives RuntimeWarning

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, nltk

```
python3 -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/local/share/nltk_data all
```

Upon running the above command in GCP, I face the following `RuntimeWarning`

```
'nltk.downloader' found in sys.modules after import of package 'nltk', but prior to execution of 'nltk.downloader'; this may result in unpredictable behaviour
```

Also I've already installed nltk. And whilst installing that, I had to add the --proxy switch. I'm assuming I'd require a proxy switch over here too, so there's a chance that might be the problem over here. But I'm unaware as to how I can add the proxy switch here.

Answer (score 1):

I created a GCE instance to install NLTK and test the command you included, and it showed the same warning message. According to this issue in the NLTK Github [repository](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/2162), the warning message appears due to how the modules are imported in the `__init__.py` file. The NLTK developer explains that refactoring the modules would break backwards compatibility. The warning message appears to be a known issue and harmless when referencing the note [here](https://doc.scalingo.com/languages/python/nltk).

In case you would like to hide the warning message, so you can use the [-W switch](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-W) from Python like so:

```
python3 -W ignore -m nltk.downloader -d ./nltk.data all
```

Another option is to manually import NLTK first in a Python one-liner script using the -c switch (the argument is the package to download, which can be referenced in [their documentation](http://www.nltk.org/data.html#installing-nltk-data)):

```
python3 -c “import nltk; nltk.download(‘all’)”

RUN python3 -c “import nltk; nltk.download(‘all’)” # When running from a Dockerfile
```

I tested both options in a GCE instance, and did not see the warning message. This documentation is external to GCP so I cannot vouch for their accuracy.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply, I'll try this (: